# Scilab, backdoor error, octave conflict

Tags: octave, scilab, recompile, lib

I installed scilab.6.0.0 and backdoor fromscilab website (which I could not find it from Application>Module maneger>atom>Technical). I moved the backdoor file my home and from scilab command line I installed it

```
-->atomsInstall('/home/user/BackDoor_0.2_5.5.bin.x86_64.linux.tar.gz')
```

Even though, it installed backdoor successfully, when I restart the scilab I got this error message with backdoor

```
Start Toolbox BackDoor
    Load macros
atomsLoad: An error occurred while loading 'BackDoor-0.2':
    lib: Old binary lib detected. Please recompile it for Scilab 6.
```

As I understand I need to update the library, but I don't know how?
Would sb tell me explicitly (because I am a newbie user of scilab) how can I get over the error?
at the and I try to connect octave and scilab and when I try to run a demo script at octave I get also this error

```
>> sci_sim_example
Scilab connection failed
```

FYI: I already installed sci_cosim package (after I downloaded the package, I write to octave prompt `>>pkg install sci_cosim_0.1.3.tar.gz`), and I load it before running the script.

How can I recompile the ***lib: Old binary lib detected***

Thank you so much for your help in advance

Comment: are these the instructions you're following? http://wiki.octave.org/Sci_cosim

Comment: Yes, I've followed them while installing

Comment: The version you downloaded seems to be incompatible with Scilab 6. I've had a go at compiling from source; in theory it should be as easy as executing the builder.sce script from within scilab, but this fails, presumably again due to incompatibilities with Scilab 6. Your best bet is  to install an older version of scilab, e.g. 5.5, and install the Backdoor binary (v2_5.5) you have there.

Comment: Actually, I've already installed old version and because of the backdoor incompatibility problem, I installed scilab 6. Well, if there is a way, like compiling from source (actually I don't know how it works), would you please write in steps?I can give it a shot at least. By the way, I am even not sure, it is either done from ubuntu prompt or scilab. Many thanks

Comment: I got it to work on mine easily but using Scilab 5.5.2. If you install _that_ version, then you don't need to mess with installers at all, just go to the atoms manager and install BackDoor from the list. There was _one_ tiny bug on Linux; I had to rename two files (scilab was looking for `backdoor.start`, but the file on disk was `BackDoor.start`, and `BackDoor.quit` to `backdoor.quit` respectively), but after that everything worked fine. I agree the octave wiki needs a few tiny changes though, I'll see if I have access to edit it. If you'd like I can write the process as an answer here.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explicit answer. Now I can figure out why scilab 6 does not work together with backdoor. Yes, wiki needs some tiny editions, as you said, '-auto' does not work at all. Besides, I will upload scilab 5.5.2, and follow your steps

Comment: I've edited the octave wiki to reflect my findings from the octave side of things :)

Comment: I've just checked the wiki [link](http://wiki.octave.org/Sci_cosim) That's very useful to mention, especially, the version of Scilab v.5.5.2. Many thanks for your contributions :)

Comment: Glad to hear it. Did you manage to get everything to work? :)

Comment: Yes, absolutely you solved the backdoor problem. Finally, I able to installed it to scilab and it launchs perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what worked for me.

- Download Scilab 5.5.2 ([link for Linux 64bit version](http://www.scilab.org/download/5.5.2/scilab-5.5.2.bin.linux-x86_64.tar.gz))
- Extract the `.tar.gz` file in your preferred system location to install it there. Generally, my preferred location to extract / install self-contained packages is inside [/opt](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/opt.html) .

  You can extract the `.tar.gz` file using your filebrowser's graphical facilities, or on the command line; if `/opt` is owned by `root` (which it usually is) you may need to change ownership after extraction. E.g. your installation might look something like this:

  ```
  cd /opt
  sudo wget http://www.scilab.org/download/5.5.2/scilab-5.5.2.bin.linux-x86_64.tar.gz
  sudo tar -xvzf ./scilab-5.5.2.bin.linux-x86_64.tar.gz
  sudo rm scilab-5.5.2.bin.linux-x86_64.tar.gz
  sudo chown $USER ./scilab-5.5.2 -R
  ```
- Launch scilab by typing

  ```
  /opt/scilab-5.5.2/bin/scilab &
  ```

  in your terminal.
- Once scilab is launched, go to `Applications`->`Module Manager ATOMS`. In the new window that comes up, click on `All modules` -> `BackDoor` -> `Install`.
  You should get a message saying "Installation done, please restart SciLab".
- Exit Scilab, and launch it again from the terminal. If you see a message:

  > atomsLoad: An error occurred while loading 'BackDoor-0.2':
  >   File "/opt/scilab-5.5.2/share/scilab/contrib/BackDoor/0.2/etc/backdoor.start" does not exist.
  >   then type the following commands in your terminal to rename the affected files:

  ```
  cd /opt/scilab-5.5.2/share/scilab/contrib/BackDoor/0.2/etc/
  mv BackDoor.start backdoor.start
  mv BackDoor.quit  backdoor.quit
  ```

  Restart SciLab again. Hopefully this time it will work and SciLab will inform you that BackDoor is listening for connections at a certain port.

---

PS. Also note that from the octave side of things, the `-auto` option is no longer accepted when you perform a `pkg install`. You will need to load the `sockets` and `sci_cosim` packages manually each time you want to use this.

Comment: I installed scilab-5.5.2 (thanks for the linux 64bit version link:) according to your answer. After I launched scilab, unfortunately, I got the _backdoor.start does not exist_ error. then I follow your solution also removing Backdoor.start and creating backdoor.start and other quit files. Finally it works. Here is my backdoor listening message.                     'Start Toolbox BackDoor
 Load macros
 Load gateways
 Load help
 Opening back door

  BackDoor: listening to connections on TCP port 28020'